# How to add inline style in element with Quill Text Editor?

Tags: javascript, quill

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6oegmkq/)

When inserting content using `dangerouslyPasteHTML`, inline styles are not inserted?

For example, margin-right is not applied to `p` element.

How to set inline styles on `p` element?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [from the docs](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#dangerouslypastehtml):

> ### dangerouslyPasteHTML
>
> Inserts content represented by HTML snippet into editor at a given index. The snippet is interpreted by Clipboard matchers, which may not produce the exactly input HTML.

Quill was made as the new generation of WYSIWYG text editor and, by design, prevents arbitrary html insertion which often made previous editors buggy and unreliable.

When you use **dangerouslyPasteHTML**, Quill is trying to build a representation of the content that makes sense and will strip anything that doesn't fit this representation (which inline-styles are a part of).

If you want to read more about this, here is an interesting conversation on this exact issue: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1896